# Probability of two disjoint events but the probability of one event is unknown

Tags: probability

I'm given that A and B are two disjoint events where $P(A) = 0.4$.

The first part of the problem asked if $P(B) = 0.8$ is possible which I answered as no since that would make $P(A \cup B)$ bigger than the sample space $P(\Omega)$.

However, the second part then asks me to find $P(A \cap B^c)$. I'm really confused on where to start since I feel like it's unsolvable since I don't actually know what $P(B)$ is. I thought it might of just been 0, but since they're disjoint $A$ is guaranteed to be a subset of $B^c$ which means the answer is a non-zero number.

I'm not sure if I'm thinking about this right and feel like I've hit a dead end from a mistake I've made.

Comment: Note that $P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c)=P(A)$ for any events $A,B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might help to draw a diagram:
[image]

$A$ and $B$ are disjoint, so they have no overlap - meaning that $A$ sits *entirely* inside $B^c$ - meaning that $A \cap B^c = A$.

Alternatively, knowing that $P(A) = P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap B^c)$ for any events $A, B$, you can just plug in the values you already know to get the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

As $A$ and $B$ are disjoint events, we have that $A \subset B^{c}$, so $A \cap B^{c} = A$.